# Configure as code with security groups and ldap

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We are trying to set up a SonarQube server (v. 6.5) to run in Kubernetes. Because of this, we need everything to be configured "as code" not through the web interface.

We have successfully set up single sign-on (SSO) against LDAP server, and that works as such. But since users can then not log out in order to log in as a static admin, we need some way to configure a group that has admin privileges.

It is my understanding that this should be done via group mapping, but all documentation and examples I can find only suggest setting up the groups through the UI.

Is there some way to configure groups via sonar.properties (or other properties file) that are then automatically mapped against groups from LDAP, and configure a group to get admin rights?

I am pretty new to SonarQube (and no ldap expert either), so I hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure groups through properties. There are web services (which are used by the UI itself) with which you could script this.

Alternately, see if you can turn on group synching with your SSO. Then you just have to grant admin rights (via the UI? via web services?) to the appropriate group in SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I believe we got the actual group sync to work, just didn't have a way of telling SonarQube to give a group certain privileges. 
I guess we will have to: 
a) dig around the api documentation (For other readers: I found this via a link in the footer of the running SonarQube)
b), and then figure out some way to execute a request against the right api-call after the container and the SonarQube server has come up.

The later is going to be a challenge, but now at least we know that we were previously chasing ghosts that  didn't exist.